# Why are some code snippets not formatted properly?

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

Sometimes my code snippets are not formatted properly. Why?

[Here's a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381257/make-transactionless-ejb-call-inside-a-transaction/37265894#37265894):

[image]

Here's the source code:

[image]

[Here's a nonworking example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219719/mybatis-cdi-wildfly-jta-requires-new)

[image]

And its source:

[image]

Comment: The second question doesn't have a language tag, and apparently none of its tags infer a language syntax highlighting either, though some maybe should.

Comment: ^ that. I just added the Java tag since it's the relevant language tag.